# Comparing lists with hamcrest

Tags: java, arraylist, hamcrest

I want to write a unittest that compares two lists. I tried to use hamcrest to get nice readability and error messages, but for some reason this does not compile:

```
List<GDSRecord> expectedRecords = getReferenceRecords(...);

List<GDSRecord> aktualRecords = gdsNetlist.getRecords();

assertThat(aktualRecords, hasItems(expectedRecords.toArray()));
```

This on the other hand does compile:

```
assertThat(asList("a", "b"), hasItems(new String[]{"a"}));
```

can someone explain the difference here? I am not getting it..,
Thanks!

Comment: General note: When asking about compiler errors, it helps to add the error message. This makes it easier for us to narrow down the list of possible problems ond focus on the relevant aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, that

```
expectedRecords.toArray()
```

would be converting it to an `Object[]`, you can change it to using [`List.toArray​(T[] a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#toArray(T%5B%5D))

```
expectedRecords.toArray(new GDSRecord[0])
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hamecrast is too complicated for such easy task.
Cleaner is to use standard junit assertions.

```
assertTrue("AktualRecords should contains expectedRecords",aktualRecords.containsAll(expectedRecords));
```

Comment: I had that solution before, but when it fails you only get as a message: "Expected <true> but was <false>" which doesnt help much. With the hamcrest approach you get the actual list contents displayed, which I feel is quite helpful for debugging.